# How to query an M:N relationship with JPA2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I have an an object (BlogPost) that contains an M:N collection of elements (Tags).

How to query for an object (BlogPost) where at least one it its Tags matches an element in a set of Tags (defined by the user) with JPA2 (Hibernate).

```
findBlogPostWithAtLeastOneMatchingTag(Collection<Tag> tags){ ???? }
```

My main problem is, that I actually need to compare two collections of tags:
- the collection of tags of the BlogPost.
- the collection I search for

I tried `Select p from Post p where p.tags in(:tags)` but it does not work, as my post entities have more than just one tag.

So what could I do instead?

My BlogPost entity looks like this. It has several Tags.

```
@Entity
public class BlogPost{

    /** The tags. */
    @ManyToMany()
    @NotNull
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @NotBlank
    private String content;

    ...
}
```

---

The solution must not be JPQL, JPA-Criteria (not Hibernate-Criteria) would be fine too.

Comment: Are you familiar with Criteria API? You can check it out and see if it suits you.

Comment: Familiar... well I "tried" to use it, but didn't find a way to make it work, neither.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you like JPA Criteria, this is the solution for you:

```
List<Integer> myTagsIds = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
myTagsIds.add(1);
myTagsIds.add(2);

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<BlogPost> cq = cb.createQuery(BlogPost.class);
Root<BlogPost> blogPost = cq.from(BlogPost.class);
SetJoin<BlogPost, Tag> tags = blogPost.join(BlogPost_.tags);
Predicate predicate = tags.get(Tag_.id).in(myTagsIds);
cq.distinct(true);
cq.where(predicate);
TypedQuery<BlogPost> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
return tq.getResultList();
```

This solution makes use of the [canonical MetaModel](http://wiki.eclipse.org/UserGuide/JPA/Using_the_Canonical_Model_Generator_%28ELUG%29) classes `BlogPost_` and `Tag_` that should be generated by your JPA implementation.

Comment: I think `person.join` should be `blog.join`?

Comment: It was blogPost.join indeed. Thanks for pointing it out. I had tested the query on classes with different names (but same relationship however)...

Comment: So this stuff with the _ suffixes is only available for EclipseLink?

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach 1:

In SQL it could be something like:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE (p.tags INTERSECT :tags IS NOT EMPTY);
```

Then apply the `@SqlResultSetMapping`.

#### Approach 2:

You can use `Criteria API` and start as you did but make a loop over `Collection<Tag> tags` as:

```
* make a union of single query results from `Select p from Post p where p.tags in(:tags)`;
* take distinct over result of union.
```

Query will be server-side and you wouldn't have to do dirty work in Java.

Comment: It's worth noting that INTERSECT is not available in mysql!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

Select t from Post t where t.tag in (select p.tag from Post p where p.id=:id)

id is the id of the current post. Basically you are selecting post with tags that are in the tags of current post.

Comment: This would actually work, if my post only had one tag (In fact it's the same idea I already had myself). I'm looking for a solution for al list of tags in Post t. I updated my question to make it clearer.