# Using a ParameterExpression as part of the In clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I would like to use a parameter expression as part of an in clause.  I would like to query for a list of Foos that have a Bar that is in a set of Bars. Is this possible?

```
Foo
    // Join, ManyToOne
    Bar getBar()

Query
    ParameterExpression<???> barParameter;

    void setup() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = ...
        CriteriaQuery<Foo> criteria = ...
        Root<Bar> root = ...

        barParameter = builder.parameter(???);

        criteria.where(
            builder.in(root.get(Foo_.bar)).value(barParameter)
        );
    }

    List<Foo> query(Set<Bar> bars) {
        TypedQuery<Foo> query = createQuery();
        query.setParameter(barParameter, bars);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11349052/870122) can be helpful: it's not about `ParameterExpression`S, but could be a starting point...

Comment: Everything I had found (including your link) has the actual data for the in clause at the time of creating the CriteriaQuery.  I have been using a pattern where the CriteriaQuery is built once and the actual parameters are set using parameter expressions.  I was just hoping there was something simple I was overlooking to use a ParameterExpression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `in` expressions you can only use primitive comparison types, so you need to make a join and compare a field of a primitive type (here I have used `Integer id`):

```
Root<Foo> foo = cq.from(Foo.class);
Join<Foo, Bar> bar = foo.join(Foo_.bar);
ParameterExpression<Collection> bars = cb.parameter(Collection.class);
cq.where(bar.get(Bar_.id).in(bars));
TypedQuery<Foo> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
Collection<Integer> barsParameter = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
barsParameter.add(1);
List<Foo> resultList = tq.setParameter(bars, barsParameter).getResultList();
```