# How to set a Collection/List to a named parameter of a JPA criteria query?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

A single named parameter can be set to a JPA criteria query something like the following. The parameter is of the type `Long` in this case.

```
public StateTable find(Long id)
{
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateTable.class);
    Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<StateTable> entityType = metamodel.entity(StateTable.class);
    Root<StateTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);

    ParameterExpression<Long> parameterExpression=criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(StateTable_.stateId), parameterExpression));

    TypedQuery<StateTable> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.setParameter(parameterExpression, id).getSingleResult();
}
```

This query inside the method returns a single object of the `StateTable` (just say state) entity which I'm dealing with and corresponds to the following JPQL query.

```
entityManager.createQuery("select s from StateTable s where s.stateId=:id")
             .setParameter("id", id)
             .getSingleResult();
```

---

I need to find more than one row that corresponds to a list of ids supplied via `java.util.List<Long>`. The following is the incomplete version of the criteria query.

```
public List<StateTable> find(List<Long> ids)
{
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateTable.class);
    Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<StateTable> entityType = metamodel.entity(StateTable.class);
    Root<StateTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);

    ParameterExpression<Long> parameterExpression = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)).value(parameterExpression));

    TypedQuery<StateTable> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.setParameter(parameterExpression, 1L).getResultList();
}
```

It uses an `in()` query but I made it return only a single row, since I don't know whether it is possible to set a list of ids to `ParameterExpression` or not.

In short, this criteria query should correspond to the following JPQL query.

```
entityManager.createQuery("from StateTable where stateId in(:id)")
             .setParameter("id", ids)
             .getResultList();
```

Is there a way to set a `List<Long>` to `ParameterExpression` as specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach worked for me.

```
public List<StateTable> find(List<Long> ids)
{
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateTable.class);
    Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<StateTable> entityType = metamodel.entity(StateTable.class);
    Root<StateTable> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);

    //ParameterExpression<Long> parameterExpression = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
    //criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)).value(parameterExpression));
    criteriaQuery.where(root.get(StateTable_.stateId).in(ids));

    TypedQuery<StateTable> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

I just added the following line.

```
criteriaQuery.where(root.get(StateTable_.stateId).in(ids));
```

removing the above commented lines from the incomplete version of the query in the question.

Comment: This does mean server-side query caching is negatively impacted. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this while using a ParameterExpression?

Comment: Until now, I saw only this even with JPA 2.1 criteria bulk update and delete.

Comment: I don't think this is array bind. If you check the actual SQL, you will see the params are still set one by one, like `in (?, ?, ?)`, not as a collection(`in (?)`), so downvote. What I see possible is Hibernate's `setParameterList()`, but is not part of JPA.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently investigating the same thing and found a solution that shouldn't impact server-side query caching.
[Using a ParameterExpression as part of the In clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845925/using-a-parameterexpression-as-part-of-the-in-clause)

Please note that this should have been a response to a comment from Jannik Jochem under this page's answer; however, I am few rep short for that, so feel free to kill this post and add a comment if you have enough rep.