# Criteria Query for Unidirectional one to many association, searching with list of entities

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I have Entities which contain Collections (OneToMany) which hold Person Entities. A person does not know to which Collection it belongs.
I want to search for MyPersons entities that contain specific Persons.
The problem is that I dont know how to search with criteria when I have a list of Persons that need to be mapped to the MyPerson Entities.
Excuse me for my bad english.
I hope someone can help.

Comment: A little more context would be useful.  What is the relation in between your entities especially MyPersons with Collections? Are you talking about database query or object filtering?

Comment: I need to retrieve all MyPersons Entities from a database, where a MyPersons Entity contains a MyPerson Entitiy from an ArrayList. And I need to do it with the Criteria API if possible.

Comment: And I did a little mistake in my Question. A MyPersons Entity holds only one Set of MyPerson Entities.

Answer (score 0):

```html
data=Collection.stream().filter(f->f.getName().equals("name")).forEach(i->{
    System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: A little context or explanation about the answer would help the user asking

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyPersons> query = builder.createQuery(MyPersons.class);
Root<MyPersons> root = query.from(MyPersons.class);
Join<MyPersons, MyNaturalPerson> join = root.join("persons");
ParameterExpression<Collection> persons = builder.parameter(Collection.class);
//Persons = filled with MyPerson Entities
query.where(join.in(persons));
TypedQuery<MyPersons> tq = session.createQuery(query);
List<?> resultList = tq.setParameter(persons, result).getResultList();
List<MyNaturalPerson> finalresult = (List<MyNaturalPerson>) resultList;
```

[Thx to a very similar Question/problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845925/using-a-parameterexpression-as-part-of-the-in-clause)