# How to load all entities in JPA given the collection of their primary keys?

Tags: java, jpa

I'd like to write a generic method in JPA 2 that can load all entities of class `T` if it is given the collection of their primary keys. Here is the signature of the desired method:

```
public <T> List<T> getEntityList(final Class<T> entityClass, final Collection<Object> primaryKeys)
```

Is it possible somehow even if I don't know the entity class nor the primary key class?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11349052/870122 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9325205/870122

Answer (score -1):

```
public <T> List<T> getEntityList(final Class<T> entityClass, final Collection<Object> primaryKeys)
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(entityClass);
    crit.add(Restrictions.in("id", primaryKeys);
return crit.list();
```

Using a criteria query and hibernate makes it pretty simple. The JPA way is [pretty similar](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiwn) I think.

Comment: but then he asks for JPA, and you give Hibernate-specific

Comment: @DataNucleus yeah I just noticed that

Comment: You cannot make sure that the primary key column is called `id`

Comment: yes, the main problem is that we don' t know before what is the primary key.

Comment: you could return each entity indifualyl using a plain old get(type, id)