# How do I write a JPA query that checks if a collection has at least one item in another collection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have this entity with this field ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    …
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

I want to write a method

```
List<User> findUsers(List<Role> roles);
```

that will return users in which a user has at least one of the roles in the parameter "roles."  How do I do that in JPA?  I know I can write

```
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
…
    criteria.where(user.get("role").in(roles)));
    final TypedQuery<User> query = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```

if the user has a single role, but in this case the user has a set, so I don't know how to adjust the above.

Comment: LazyCollection is a Hibernate annotation, not a JPA's annotation, therefore I would avoid to use it if the requirement is to write a JPA's CriteriaBuilder query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11349052/870122), you can use [`Expression#in()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#in(java.lang.Object...)) method in this way, provided that you use a basic property as argument to the `in` expression:

```
Join<User, Role> rolesJoin = user.join("roles");
List<Integer> rolesIds = new ArrayList();
for (Role role : roles) {
    rolesIds.add(role.getId());
}
criteria.where(rolesJoin.get("id").in(rolesIds));
```

Hopefully there are also other ways to make it work, but I haven't found any other, yet.